# Write custom SQL Query in DataObject::get()

Tags: php, mysql, silverstripe

I am using Silverstripe version 2.4 . I did not update to new version because I have made many changes and now it is impossible for me to migrate to newer version.

I have a custom SQL query and I want the query to run in DataObject::get();
Here is my Query

SELECT STL.* FROM `Page` P join `SiteTree_Live` STL on P.ID = STL.ID join `Site` S on P.SiteID = S.ID where S.ID = 60 and STL.ShowInMenus = 1 and STL.ParentID = 0 and STL.CanViewType <> 'NotLoggedInUsers' ..

How can I write this query in DataObject::get();

Any help would be greatly appreciated.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is using the ORM to build that query, in 2.4 it could be done like this (only works if class `Site` has a `has_many` to `Page`, which I assume is the case here):

```
$site = DataObject::get('Site', 'ID = 60');
// the line below assumes that the has_many in site is called "Pages"
$pages = $site->Pages("ShowInMenus = 1 AND ParentID = 0 AND CanViewType <> 'NotLoggedInUsers'");
```

---

alternatively, if you want to save yourself that extra query for Site, you can do it with 1 DataObject::get() using the join parameter. should look something like this:

```
$pages = DataObject::get(
    'Page', 
    "Site.ID = 60 AND ShowInMenus = 1 AND ParentID = 0 AND CanViewType <> 'NotLoggedInUsers'", 
    null, 
    'LEFT JOIN Site ON Site.ID = Page.SiteID'
);
```